# How to re-sign the ipa file?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ipa

How do I sign the .ipa file with a provisioning profile after I generate an IPA like the following with a different provision profile? I would like to sign the IPA with an ad-hoc provisioning profile for beta testing, and then re-sign the exact IPA with an app submission provisioning profile for the app store.

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-sign IPA (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone)

Answer (score 217):

It's really easy to do from the command line. I had a gist of a script for doing this. It has now been incorporated into the ipa_sign script in https://github.com/RichardBronosky/ota-tools which I use daily. If you have any questions about using these tools, don't hesitate to ask.

The heart of it is this:

```sh
CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=`xcrun --find codesign_allocate`; export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE
IPA="/path/to/file.ipa"
PROVISION="/path/to/file.mobileprovision"
CERTIFICATE="Name of certificate: To sign with" # must be in keychain
# unzip the ipa
unzip -q "$IPA"
# remove the signature
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature
# replace the provision
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
# sign with the new certificate (--resource-rules has been deprecated OS X Yosemite (10.10), it can safely be removed)
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" Payload/*.app
# zip it back up
zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload
```

Your new signed app is called resigned.ipa

Comment: 7 up votes and not a single question. I guess my bash is just that clear.

Comment: im getting an error message saying "security: unable to open "/var/folders/74/kpcwmb6j1pn92kr8mtvm2mwh0000gn/T/./resign.I9DrKi7B/Payload/AtlantaJournal.app/embedded.mobileprovision" for reading: No such file or directory".

Comment: @RahmathullahMPulikkal I see I had errantly hardcoded a path in the gist. You really should be using https://github.com/RichardBronosky/ota-tools/blob/master/ipa_sign instead of the gist. It's the maintained code.

Comment: I got this error _security: unable to open "/tmp/resign.MyApp.WObe2/my.mobileprovision" for reading: No such file or directory_  easily fixed by moving the cp up in the code. Thank you!

Comment: @AlbertoM by moving what? I don't understand what it means.

Comment: @iMx, I just pushed an update that ought to fix this for you.

Comment: @RichardBronosky thanks, but I still get this error. But it works in terminal, if I enter the commands manually.

Comment: @iMx can you please send me a transcript of what does and doesn't work. Please include a `git log -1 | cat; git status` from within the ota-tools directory.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @yeesterbunny. It encourages me to spend more time on stackoverflow... which is especially important when people choose not to accept the highest rated answers as "The correct answer."

Comment: after i run the script on the terminal, nothing happened, please advice

Comment: You may got an warning / error on --resource-rules parameters, which have been deprecated in OS X Yosemite (10.10), simply delete this parameter solve this issue.

Comment: RichardBronosky many many thanks for this - spent hours trying different solutions before finding yours.  Just to help future people - I needed the excellent pointer from @kenji which I almost didn't see as it was at the very end of the comments.  I suggest adding  this pointer into your answer or your script.

Comment: One little note: it looks like `CodeResources` is now located _inside_ of the `_CodeSignature` folder, so you just need to remove that folder.

Comment: @simmons comment added to the script

Comment: After doing this, Application Loader still can't accept because the version is the same as the previous one

Comment: @KarenAnne, changing the version number would be a different task than what was asked for by the OP. I would suggest looking for an answer to your task and asking a new question if you can't find it.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I see. Because we cannot just re-submit new app to TestFlight by changing provisioning profile. It is not accepted by application if it has the same build and version number as the previous one. Thanks.

Comment: @KarenAnne I think thin may be what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975049/change-app-version-with-only-ipa-file-provided-no-xcode I haven't tried it yet but I'm going to work on it today. We can both report back and I'll add it to my answer if it works. Thanks for the idea. I'm always looking to improve my answers.

Comment: BTW, I was able to use the info in that answer to change the `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` of an IPA for which I did NOT have the source code and submit it to TestFlight. My team was able to install and test the app. We shipped it to Apple and it is now in the store. I've modified ipa_sign to incorporate this feature and after more personal testing I'll release an update.

Comment: While this bash script works perfectly, if your app has entitlements it will not. You just need to add 
    `security cms -D -i "$PROVISION" > provision.plist`
    `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy  -x -c 'Print :Entitlements' provision.plist > entitlements.plist` before copying the provisioning profile
    and then do `/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app` instead of the current code signing.
I only realised that the gist is the up to date version (handling entitlements) after reading the comments!

Comment: Hello, sorry I am totally new to bash and code signing :/ here is the error I get when executing the bash from a terminal window: Using temp dir: /tmp/resign. ...
App has BundleDisplayName '...' and BundleShortVersionString '...'
App has BundleIdentifier  '...' and BundleVersion ...
security: SecPolicySetValue: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.
App has provision         '...', which supports '...'
security: unable to open "/tmp/resign..../....mobileprovision" for reading: No such file or directory ----> any thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: `/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE"` is not working anymore. It needs to be `/usr/bin/codesign --force -s "$CERTIFICATE" -v Payload/*.app`

Comment: What worked for me today: Execute `security find-identity -v` to determine the ID of your signing identity. Invoke `/usr/bin/codesign --force -s YOUR_IDENTITY -v Payload/*.app` to actually sign the app.

Comment: You may need to add a step for extracting the current entitlements use it as part of codesign

Comment: It's shows me unable to install the app after performing the steps.

@BrunoBronosky any idea about this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as @RushDroid. Did you find any solution?

Comment: zip -qr is what I was missing. I was using the compress option in Finder and was not working.

Answer (score 39):

Check [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) for an easy tool on how to do this!

[edit] after some fudling around, I found a solution to keychain-aware resigning. You can check it out at https://gist.github.com/Weptun/5406993

Comment: is there any tool which can change the Display name along with Bundle id while resigning? This will help to have different display names for different environements. like App-Dev, App-QA, App-Stage etc.

Comment: Yes, the floatsign.sh does exactly that.

Comment: Works. Simple and beautiful.

Answer (score 16):

Kind of old question, but with the latest XCode, `codesign` is easy:

```
$ codesign -s my_certificate example.ipa 

$ codesign -vv example.ipa
example.ipa: valid on disk
example.ipa: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Comment: @Pavel This question was answered back when iOS 6.x was the latest version. Since then, we've had two major releases, which obviously changed many things. You might wish to limit your searches to answers that target current technology.

Comment: It worked for me. you have to replace "my_certificate" with the name of the key in your key chain.

Comment: `codesign` command is also used in @BrunoBronosky response. I'm not able to use it directly on "*.ipa" file, and the "-vv" options always returns `code object is not signed at all` on files that I know they are signed...

Answer (score 16):

The answers posted here all didn't quite work for me. They mainly skipped signing embedded frameworks (or including the entitlements).

Here's what's worked for me (it assumes that one ipa file exists is in the current directory):

```sh
PROVISION="/path/to/file.mobileprovision"
CERTIFICATE="Name of certificate: To sign with" # must be in the keychain

unzip -q *.ipa
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature/

# Replace embedded provisioning profile
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision

# Extract entitlements from app
codesign -d --entitlements :entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/

# Re-sign embedded frameworks
codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/Frameworks/*

# Re-sign the app (with entitlements)
codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/

zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload

# Cleanup
rm entitlements.plist
rm -r Payload/
```

Comment: Useful comment from the post above (Rich): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file#comment62841505_10905855

Comment: This is a great next step, but it is missing signing of extensions. I added one more line, before the app signing: codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app/Plugins/*

Comment: @Pat, what if appexes have different provisions?

Comment: I suppose you'd have to have a mapping or association of entitlements for each extension. Perhaps a folder that has the extension name and an entitlement for it, stored externally so you can do a for loop over the extensions and reference the appropriate entitlement by the extension name.

Answer (score 15):

Fastlane's [sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh) provides a fairly robust solution for resigning IPAs.

From their README:

> Resign
>
> If you generated your `ipa` file but want to apply a different code signing onto the ipa file, you can use `sigh resign`:
>
> `fastlane sigh resign`
>
> `sigh` will find the ipa file and the provisioning profile for you if they are located in the current folder.
>
> You can pass more information using the command line:
>
> `fastlane sigh resign ./path/app.ipa --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: Felix Krause" -p "my.mobileprovision"`

It will even handle [provisioning profiles for nested applications](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/7783) (eg. if you have watchkit apps)

Answer (score 8):

I've updated Bryan's code for my Sierra iMac:

```
# this version was tested OK vith macOs Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73) on oct 0th, 2017
# original ipa file must be store in current working directory 

IPA="ipa-filename.ipa"
PROVISION="path-to.mobileprovision"
CERTIFICATE="hexadecimal-certificate-identifier" # must be in keychain
# identifier maybe retrieved by running: security find-identity -v -p codesigning

# unzip the ipa
unzip -q "$IPA"

# remove the signature
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature

# replace the provision
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision

# generate entitlements for current app
cd Payload/
codesign -d --entitlements - *.app > entitlements.plist
cd ..
mv Payload/entitlements.plist entitlements.plist

# sign with the new certificate and entitlements
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" '--entitlements' 'entitlements.plist'  Payload/*.app

# zip it back up
zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload
```

Comment: i git the following error  entitlements.plist: unrecognized blob type (accepting blindly)
entitlements.plist: invalid length in entitlement blob

Comment: can you share you entitlement file contents?

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

1. Unzip the .ipa file by changing its extension with .zip
2. Go to Payload. You will find .app file
3. Right click the .app file and click Show package contents
4. Delete the `_CodeSigned` folder
5. Replace the `embedded.mobileprovision` file with the new provision profile
6. Go to KeyChain Access and make sure the certificate associated with the provisional profile is present
7. Execute the below mentioned command:
   `/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Certificate Name" --resource-rules "Payload/Application.app/ResourceRules.plist" "Payload/Application.app"`
8. Now zip the Payload folder again and change the .zip extension with .ipa

Hope this helpful.

For reference follow below mentioned link:
http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/codesign-re-signing-an-ipa-between-apple-accounts/

Answer (score 1):

Try this app
http://www.ketzler.de/2011/01/resign-an-iphone-app-insert-new-bundle-id-and-send-to-xcode-organizer-for-upload/

It supposed to help you resign the IPA file. I tried it myself but couldn't get pass an error with Entitlements.plist. Could just be a problem with my project. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign and it is working really well.