# Distribute in house iOS app to customers without distributing source code

Tags: ios, key, private, ipa

We created a IOS app and want to distribute it to our customers. The problem is that we can't give them our source code and they can't give their private key to us. How can we distribute the iOS app to our customers? We now have three different customers.

Can we create an ipa without code signing, then give it to our customers and let them code sign the `.ipa` file?

Comment: Doesn't Apple dislike installing stuff past their Market in the first place? I suggest you switch to Android - installing an .apk from anywhere from the internet is a breeze.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: @Femaref: Shh, I'm trying to be an obnoxious fanboy here, can't you see!? (Why not post that as an answer btw)

Answer (score 3):

Just give them the IPA.  It's probably easier for it to be signed with your key than not at all - it doesn't matter if it is already signed.  The IPA can be unzipped like a normal zip file and then re-signed with the `codesign` tool [as shown in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file).  They can then re-zip it to obtain a properly-signed IPA file.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I have two related quetions:the first : is it permitted by apple that re-signing a ipa？ To do so whether there are legal risks? the second: Can we sign an ipa by one provision for APP ID A, and re-sign it by another provision for APP ID B?

Comment: No legal problems.  You would have to change the App ID in the `Info.plist` file before re-signing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testflight, for example. Or Ad-Hoc distribution.

Comment: The problem he has is with signing, not distribution.  A distribution mechanism alone cannot solve his problem.

Comment: You are right, misread the question. They can really give IPA to customer for re-signing.