# Alter Minimum OS Version of IPA without XCode, iOS 8+

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

This is a long shot but... I've been mistakenly left with an IPA instead of an XCode project by a teammate who's gone off on holiday and it urgently needs uploading to iTunes Connect. The problem, when I tried to upload the IPA via Application Loader the Minimum OS version was set to 5.0, and I got an error that this was too low, had to be at least 5.1.1.  I went through the process here: 
[Change app Version with only IPA file provided (no xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975049/change-app-version-with-only-ipa-file-provided-no-xcode) to edit the Minimum OS via the Info.plist but I encountered the same issue as the final comment on this question, the resulting IPA will upload but will not install.

I've done a ton of searches for other solutions but have only managed to find old, pre-iOS 8 answers, all the same solution as within the link above - If anyone knows if its still possible to alter the minimum OS version of an IPA without being able to do this through XCode much appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: attach the device to xcode while installing. there must be a detailed error message posted to the console that may help you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about this, I've not used XCode purely as a way to get error messages when I didn't create the build in XCode, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to phix23 who gave a tip to check the error messages when trying to install, it turned out to be an issue with the entitlements. I got this fixed, uploaded to iTunes Connect and distributed via TestFlight.

There were a couple of steps I followed to sort this out which I think are worth noting here incase anyone else needs to do this. After unzipping the IPA and editing the Info.plist to change the Minimum OS, I needed to sort out the entitlements.

- I created an entitlements .xcent file using the [Python 2 script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111005022656/http://246tnt.com/iPhone/gen_entitlements.py) contained in the 5th comment [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110812061305/https://forums.adobe.com/thread/751326) to do this. I added the entitlements `<key>beta-reports-active<key><true/>` (to use TestFlight) and `<key>get-task-allow<key><false/>` & `<key>aps-environment<key><string>production<string>`(because these were in my provisioning profile) to the python script before generating the entitlements .xcent.
- The entitlements need to match the provisioning profile, I checked those using the commands found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG68).
- There is also a file inside the *.app called something like `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` so I also edited this to match the entitlement `.xcent` file I generated with the python script using a text editor. Just to be sure.

When resigning I left out the  `--resource-rule` option (which didn't seem to work for me) but included `--entitlements` option, pointing to the entitlement `.xcent` file .

Also, it's worth noting that if the IPA had a Payload and a Symbols directory when unzipped, select them both and compress into an archive to rezip, rather than just rezipping the Payload.

Comment: Indeed, `ResourceRules.plist` isn't used anymore, so you won't find it in most IPAs anymore.