# Is it possible to add content into ipa file?

Tags: ios

In Android we can extract apk files and add content of these files into a single file. we can also entry the newly added activity in android.manifest file.

Is it possible to add content in ipa and rebuilt it for device?
Please help me.

Comment: hi , please check this like . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975049/change-app-version-with-only-ipa-file-provided-no-xcode

Comment: Thanks Ilesh, but it is not for me because i wana add more viewcontrollers inside of ipa directly.

Comment: it is not possible as ipa is an arhieve file , if any explicit file needs to be added then just add it in xcode and again make ipa .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add content in ipa and rebuilt it for device?

**No.** From your comment above, you're looking to modify the application itself by adding view controllers. That would require rebuilding the application, and you'd need the source code for the app for that, not the .ipa file.

It *is* possible to modify resource files in the archive and then re-sign the .ipa file, so you could change an icon, replace images, etc. But adding view controllers is different because they need to be compiled and linked with the rest of the application code.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot modify any ipa file once it is built. However, you can view the content of particular app file by converting ipa to app . After you have converted an ipa file to app file you can check the content by right click on it and the choose show package content.

How to convert ipa to app file:
Right click ipa file -> open with archive utility (or winrar), it will create an app file, right click app file - > show package content.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get source code of the app and edit according to your requirements then it may not be possible with the app available to app store but i can't say for enterprise app.

Answer (score 0):

iPA stands for iPhone Achieve and any changes in iPA can produce problem to build so  if it needs to add few Xib or Viewcontroller then its better to add these in xcode and run and build new iPA . Hope this helps.