# Increment version number directly in the .app?

Tags: ios

If there is a .app which is ready for submission to Testflight or the app store, but the version number needs bumping, then is there any reason why the version number in the Info.plist can't just be changed and then resubmitted? Or is a new build/archive needed to be generated, if so why?

Comment: Its possible to do so according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975049/change-app-version-with-only-ipa-file-provided-no-xcode

Answer (score 0):

A new build and archive IS required in order to change your app's version number.

The version number is "baked in" to the app, and the app is code signed with that baked-in version.

In order to change the version number you have to re code-sign the app, which is part of the build and archive process.

Comment: Thanks, however an app can be resigned totally independently of the build process using codesign. i.e the build process can create the .ipa and/or the .xcarchive. Then the .app within either the .ipa or the .xcarchive can be resigned. The .mobileprovision files can be replaced and it can be resigned using the codesign tool. Therefore where exactly is this baked-inness located?