# How to update provisioning profile that has expired (in testflight)

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight

We have an ios app managed through testflight which has an expired provisioning profile.   We have generated a new profile in the apple developer portal, downloaded it,  and uploaded to testflight, under the specific build (using permissions,  add/update profile.)  The uploaded profile is saved, and appears in a green notification in testflight.   However,  when trying to open the app from a device,  a message is shown stating that the provisioning profile for this build has expired.

Is it necessary to re-compile the app and upload a new build to testflight?   Or is it possible to somehow have the app utilize the new provisioning profile without a new build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's necessary to recompile unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this without recompiling. Not directly through Testflight though.

All you need is the old build (.ipa) and check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905855/3619504 . It shows everything you may need. When you download the scripts sources, there's an example in Readme.md file on how to use ipa_sign script.

After resigning you will be able to reupload the newly signed build to Testflight.

Comment: Thanks!  That's __exactly__  what I needed.