# Developer sent me .ipa file without any additional information. How can I upload it to the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipa

our developer solely sent us an ipa file (no provisioning and so on). Now I struggle to upload it into the store. We have a developer account, but I do not know which bundle ID to use or which provisionig file. Is there a simple way of uploading the ipa file into the store?

Comment: No, you will need to have at least the bundle ID as register in provisioning profile. Also an app needs to be singed with a profile, which is linked to the bundle ID. If your app is not signed correctly you will not be able to upload the app. Uploading can be done with either Xcode or [ApplicationLoader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/9_UsingApplicationLoader/UsingApplicationLoader.html)

Comment: thanks for this information and confirmation of my thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

If ipa file is not yet signed with correct key and provisioning profile this ipa should be resigned with your credentials.

1. Create bundle id in iTunesConnect (I think this is not iTunesConnect but some of the Apple sub-sites, there is instructions for that on the page where App is created);
2. Create App in iTunesConnect with this bundle Id;
3. Create provisioning profile for this App;
4. If you do not have yet generate distribution certificate and corresponding private key;
5. I do not sure about simple way to change bundle id if your ipa has different bundle id from required one. Probably you can open contents of the ipa and edit Info.plist file before resigning ipa.
6. Resign existing ipa with your distribution private key and provisioning profile for this App. For example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905855/2546685 is details how to do that. Here http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/codesign-re-signing-an-ipa-between-apple-accounts/ is other instruction.
7. Complete App details and ensure that App is in Waiting for binary stage;
8. Upload ipa to AppStore, probably Application Loader is the way in this case.

iTunesConnect usually have at least short instructions for each step.