# Can not install developer certified iOS app using ideviceinstaller or fruitstrap

Tags: ios, appium

I got developer certified .ipa file from developement team for automation. I tried to install this .ipa to my iPhone 5 using both ideviceinstaller and fruitstrap but it stucks at 70% and gives following error

AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402620395

I think this is related to provisioning profile used while creating build. Do I need to send them UDID of my device and ask them to add it their provisioning profile?

Thanks & Regards
Changdeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their developer account is a standard Apple Developer Program (individual or company), they have to provision your UDID in their Provisioning Portal, regenerate the MobileProvisioning file and sign the app again using this file.

If their developer account is an Apple Enterprise Developer Program account, provisioning UDIDs is not necessary, but App Store distribution is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I read somewhere that if the build is signed with Apple Enterprise Developer Program then that can not be used for automation. I might be wrong though

Comment: Once they add my UDID in provisioning profile, will I need to do anything on my device like installing new provisioning profile or something,

Comment: I don't think it will work for the Enterprise Developer Program, since it's a Distribution certificate. You need to sign it with a Developer certificate. Try with the enterprise one after you get your UDID added, and if that doesn't work, I'll give you my script to resign so you can deploy with Appium/fruitstrap.

Comment: Hi @sheeptest , I have raised request to add UDID but there's no update from dev team, I think I should proceed with resigning the app. It will be great if you can share script or steps to resign the .ipa file. Thanks a lot friend :) You have always been a great help.

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav In order to be able to use the newly provisioned UDID, you should have access to the regenerated mobileprovisioning file. As far as signing the app, this thread looks like it could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to provide dev team with UDID of your device. Dev team will than add your UDID in ADHOC Provisioning profile.

AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402620395 is mostly provisioning profile issue.

Comment: Thanks @Paresh. Your answer is suitable but since andreimarinescu's answer has more details , I am choosing his answer,thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and none of the aforementioned solutions helped.  The app was building fine on xcode but not when launching via my code.  Turned out my DesiredCapabilities were wrong.

Reduced them to the basic values only and it all worked correctly:

```
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone"); // Doesnt seem to care about actual name
   capabilities.setCapability("udid", "88111111111111111111111438");
   capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "/Users/charlies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-emehinyoruvvntgoasdscogolux/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app");
```