# Submit to Appstore from a Team Admin Account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I need to submit an app to the Appstore , My client wants me to submit it and he's the Team Agent and I am a Team Admin.

From what I have read from the Apple documentation this is not possible, only a Team Agent can submit apps. Are there any workarounds ?

Is it possible to create the build from account , give it to my client submit to the AppStore ?

Basically do a build and archive in xCode and give him the IPA to upload it to iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `.ipa` file and send it to Team Agent.

He must resign the app as it's shown in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905855/296651

Than the `.ipa` is ready to submit to AppStore.