# Publishing IOS app on client's Enterprise App Store without source coce

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

I am developing an IOS app for a client.  My client would like to publish the app on their private Enterprise App Store which is provided by MobileIron.  However, I will not disclose the source code to my client.  Is anyone familiar to MobileIron? Can my client publish the app on their Enterprise App Store if only an api file is provided?  How to achieve it? Thank you!

Comment: @JayBhalani: I've now reviewed a lot of your edits. Thank you for doing that, but a change comment of _"i have change some code"_ is actually quite useless… especially if you didn't change the code. Please use more descriptive comments, like _"Fixed formatting"_, _"Improved grammar"_, _"Corrected some spelling mistakes"_ and the like.

Comment: @DarkDust: You sure that was the right window?

Comment: I self publish e apps - you need all the certs, then you build an ipa and xml file - only those two files are needed. Don't know mobileiron.

Comment: @SebastianKeller: Unfortunately, there is no "right window" for these kind of messages so I needed to spam one of the questions said user has edited.

Comment: @DarkDust: Sorry, I don't get your point.

Comment: I just found a technology called app resign.  But I am still trying to understand it.  Can my client resign my api file with their certificate and publish the resigned app to their enterprise app store?

Comment: @R-o-g-e-r did you see my answer for resigning an app? If yes, did it help? If so, could you accept it using the green check on the left hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Path of least resistance:

- ask them for an invitation as a member of their Enterprise portal
- archive and sign the app with a development cert & provisioning profile out of that portal
- send them the .xcarchive file out of Organizer
- they can then pop open the .xcarchive file in XCode, won't see the code, and can re-sign with their Enterprise cert and profile

The other answer will work but it's a pain in the neck compared to the above.

Answer (score 0):

To resign an existing IPA do following steps in the terminal:

```
rm -rf Payload/<yourapp>.app/_CodeSignature/
cp <a valid and made for your bundle>.mobileprovision Payload/<yourapp>.app/embedded.mobileprovision


codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: <company>" --resource-rules Payload/<yourapp>.app/ResourceRules.plist Payload/<yourapp>.app
zip -r render3d.ipa Payload
```

Then remove the app from the device with Xcode 
and drag the new ipa into xcode onto the device

EDIT:
see also:
[Re-sign IPA (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone) and 
[How to re-sign the ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file/10905855#10905855)