# Resign iOS app from iTunes with developer profile

Tags: ios

Hi  I am trying to automate Gmail app with Appium but I am not able to do because the iOS app is signed with distribution identity Appium works only with developer entitlements so I want to  resign the app with Developer entitlements how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the entitlements when using [codesign(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html). Use the `--entitlements` parameter to change the entitlements.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905855/909655) for how to re-sign an app.