# App Distribution Provisioning Profile and Signing Issues

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I've been trying to publish my app (on ios for the first time) for a few days now. Every time I try to submit, I usually get an error in the application loader telling me that the provisioning profile doesn't line up with the signing identity. I can't figure this out! Here is what I've done:

- created an iOS Distibution signing identity via Xcode account management
- created an App ID (wildcard) via apple dev portal
- created an app store (distribution) provisioning profile (associated with said App ID and iOS signing ID) and installed it on my mac
- Using RoboVM tools, I generate an IPA with said signing identity and distribution provisioning profile. (Because this is a LibGdx game)
- created an App in itunes connect (bundle ID being that of the one used for my app ID)

When I try to send to itunes connect via application loader, I get an error reading "The executable must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile." This is driving me insane so I thought I would see if I could find help here. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Turns out my mac was mixing up delicately named signing identities. I deleted them all and redid the process. works now!

Comment: try manually signing the IPA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things:

1. Do you select the right certificate in the profile?
2. Do you select the right profile in the Xcode?
3. Certificate and profile are valid.

Comment: Turns out my mac was mixing up signing identities. I deleted them all and redid the process. works now!

Comment: @user3854855 Year,check your wastebasket.If your profile is there,some strange error will occur.