# can we re-sign the appstore build with our development certificates?

Tags: ios, ipa

Can we re-sign the app store ipa of some application with our development certificates and provisioning profiles?

I could re-sign the IPA, but unable to install it on my device.

Answer (score -1):

"resign"? You mean re-sign, as in sign it with a different certificate? No, you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.yes to re-sign it with a different certificates. I found this link on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file.