# provisioning profile got expire

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

My provisioning profile got expire today, Now customer is not able to launch the app in there device.I have regenerate the provisioning profile , Still customer cant launch the app , Do I have to make a new build again? I did not upload the app to the appstore, user downloaded it from the internal link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, with new provisioning profile you have to generate new build or ipa, and then register device with this provisioning profile can install your application.

Comment: Do I have to make a release every year just for provisioning profile ?

Comment: no, once you put your app on app store then you not required to change anything. but when you submit your app or your update at that time you required to have latest provisioning profile and certificate(i mean not expired).

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You need to create a new provisioning profile, then build a new `IPA` using it. So all the registered device will be able to install an app.

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning profile is shipped along with your app if you do this with the app ipa - Rename ipa to zip and Unzip - you will see inside the Payload an app file - right click to see contents and you will see the provisioning profile.

Thats the reason why you have to resign the app with new provisioning profile and upload it.

Also check this if you want to resign with a different certificate
[How to re-sign the ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file)