# Generating unsigned IPA

Tags: ios, xcode

We have an enterprise client and we just developed an application for them. They ask us an unsigned IPA (to sign and publish the app), but as far as we know, the unsigned IPA generation is not possible in the latest version of xCode/iTunes.

Or are there any possible way to generate an unsigned IPA with the latest version of xCode?

Comment: Just export an adhoc build

Comment: Just give them xcarchive made with automatically signing

Comment: They insist the IPA because of their internal process. But this is not possible, right?

Comment: I suggest signing with your certificate just to get the IPA, and they can re-sign the IPA. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file/10905855

Comment: just create development ipa with auto sign.